# Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors not working

Tags: security, http-headers

I'm running an OpenLiteSpeed server and would like to only allow webpages that start with a specific url on my site (e.g. `https://example.com/video/**`) to be iframed by others. (I want to allow anyone to add an iframe to their site, but they can only iframe `https://example.com/video/**`)

I added this line to my headers `Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com/video/"`, but the iframe (placed on another domain) won't load, and I get this error in console: `Refused to frame 'https://example.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com/video/".`. I also tried without `'self'` and it still didn't work.

I would really appreciate if someone can assist me with this!

Thanks!

Comment: Have solved it? I've the same problem

Comment: @YomnaMansour Unfortunately not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258107/frame-ancestors-of-content-security-policy-is-not-working-in-chrome-firefox-and